# Using quotation to programmatically create a S3 generic

Tags: r, quote, tidyeval

I want to create an S3 generic in the global environment from a function. I took a look at `R.methodsS3::setGenericS3.default` and came up with the following:

```
create_generic <- function(nm) {
  src <- sprintf("%s <- function(obj, ...) UseMethod(\"%s\")", nm, nm)
  expr <- parse(text = src)
  print(expr)
  eval(expr, env = .GlobalEnv)
}

create_generic("cat")
#> expression(cat <- function(obj, ...) UseMethod("cat"))
cat
#> function (obj, ...) 
#> UseMethod("cat")
```

This works how I'd like it to. However, I've been trying to make this work using quotation and I'm stuck:

```
library(rlang)

create_generic2 <- function(nm) {
  expr <- expr(!!sym(nm) <- function(obj, ...) UseMethod(!!nm))
  print(expr)
  eval(expr, env = .GlobalEnv)
}

create_generic2("dog")
#> dog <- function(obj, ...) UseMethod("dog")
dog
#> function(obj, ...) UseMethod(!!nm)
```

This makes use of `tidyeval` since that's what I'm familiar with, but I'd like to see what this looks like in base R.

I'm interested in any version of this that works without the string manipulation in `create_generic`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R:

```
create_generic <- function(fun_name) {
  new_fun <- function(obj, ...) UseMethod(fun_name)
  assign(fun_name, new_fun, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

cat("hi\n")
# hi

create_generic("cat")

cat("hi\n")
# Error in UseMethod(fun_name) : 
#   no applicable method for 'cat' applied to an object of class "character"

cat.character <- base::cat

cat("hi\n")
# hi
```

Comment: Woops. I did this and then just printed the function, never tried it out. The `tidyverse` version above also works.

Comment: Note that `create_generic("g"); environment(g)` is not the global environment.

Comment: Right if you don't inline the generic name and rely on the closure env to pass it in with a variable you cannot change the environment to something specific like the global env.

Comment: Sanity checking myself here: the _binding_ environment for the generic is the global environment, but the _enclosing_ environment is the execution environment of `create_generic`? So doing something like `environment(g) <- globalenv()` will result in an error when trying to use `g` because `fun_name` won't be in the enclosing environment anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `expr_interp()` to use unquoting operators within functions:

```
create_generic <- function(name, env = globalenv()) {
  gen <- expr_interp(function(obj, ...) {
    UseMethod(!!name)
  })

  environment(gen) <- env
  assign(name, gen, envir = env)
}
```

The prefix is `expr_` because it is (internally) generic over expression wrappers, e.g. formulas and functions.

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer `globalenv()` to `.GlobalEnv`?

Comment: There's no reason that really matters (it is a bit more difficult to mask functions than objects but it's unlikely that `.GlobalEnv` will ever get masked)